# If read returns -1 is the socket automatically closed?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

```
  out.close ();
  in.read ( ByteBuffer.allocate ( 1 ) );
  in.close ();
```

In the above code snippet, `out` is a `WritableByteChannel` and `in` is a `ReadableByteChannel`. This code would be found at the end of processing once one of the peers has sent the EOT signal. `close()` is called on `out` and then `in` is read to get the EOF from the socket from the remote peer. When `read()` returns -1, it indicates that the peer has closed the socket. Is the `close()` on the next line redundant because the local socket has already been automatically closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Receiving end-of-stream from the peer and closing the channel are two different things. The end-of-stream simply means that no more data will be received, but the channel is still open on the local side. You should still call `close()` to release any local resources that are being used.

Answer (score 2):

> When read() returns -1, it indicates that the peer has closed the socket.

*His* socket. Not yours. The *connection* is presently half-closed, in the inbound direction. It is up to you to close your end, i.e. your socket.